# Is it possible to define a bijection from nonnegative to positive numbers?

Tags: functions

Let $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ be the set of nonnegative numbers and $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ the set of positive numbers, that is

$$
\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0} = \{\,x \geq 0 \mid x \in \mathbb{R} \,\}
$$

and

$$
\mathbb{R}_{> 0} = \{\,x > 0 \mid x \in \mathbb{R} \,\}
$$

Is it possible to define a bijection $f$ between these two sets?

Comment: Please show what you have tried. People will likely not respond with an answer because threads without shown attempts get deleted. I've had several of my answers disappear this way.

Comment: Why not? A simple example would be $f(x) = x + 1$..from the set of non-negative numbers $\to$ positive numbers...

Comment: @ProfessorofStupidity But this map is not bijective in the non-negative reals.

Comment: @Peter But we have to find bijection from non-negatives to positives. In that case this holds? Right? Or I am not able to understand your point...

Comment: We have no solution for $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}$ for example with a non-negative $x$. Hence this map is not surjective.

Comment: @Favst Well, I agree with the principle, but showing functions that surely aren't bijections didn't seem very smart to me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, of course.  First map every number that is not a non-negative integer to itself.  Then map every non-negative integer n to n+1.

Comment: Clever solution (+1)

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to define the bijection without mapping any element to itself (for reasons that remain mysterious, I thought it would break injectivity). So, now I'm curious if there is a solution with the extra constraint that $f(x) \neq x$ for each x.

Comment: @BlackBrain doesnt $x \mapsto x+1$ work there to?

Answer (score 1):

You can also take every $[n,n+1)$ interval and map it into $(n,n+1]$ by reflecting it.

The idea here being mapping $[0,\infty)$ into $(0,\infty]$ via $\frac{1}{x}$, but we can only do it if the right extreme of the second interval is included. Luckily, we can cover $\mathbb{R}$ with intervals of such form.

Comment: If we choose $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ , we cannot map $0$. But the reflecting idea should work.

Answer (score 1):

Of course. Let f be from the set with 0 to the set without 0:

f(x) = x when x is not integer;

f(0)= 1

f(1) = 2

f(2) = 3

etc.

Answer (score 0):

The have the same cardinality, so a bijection exists. You mentioned in a comment that you're also interested in a function that doesn't have any fixed points. You can adapt roddick's answer by just mixing up the intervals. For instance, you could send $[0,1)$ to $(10,11]$, $[1,2)$ to $(11,12]$, $[2,3)$ to $(0,1]$, and so on.